# dax contains() not showing Tru but should be

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm stumped here. I have this measure.

```
Contains = IF(CONTAINS(Flags, Flags[FlagsConcat], SELECTEDVALUE(SlicerFlags[FlagNames])),1,-1)
```

The concatenated column looks something like this

```
Flags

id      Bco Nat Gur Ga  An  Sim Oak Ort FlagsConcat

1826    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   Oakpoint,Orthoselect
1784    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   Oakpoint,Orthoselect
1503    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   Guardian
1502    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   Guardian
1500    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   Guardian
1499    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   Guardian
1326    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   Guardian
925 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   Guardian
```

and here is the values I am grabbing from the selectedvalue()

```
FlagNames

Benco
National
Guardian-Simply Clear
Guardian
Angel Align
Simply Clear
Oakpoint
Orthoselect
None
```

If I select Guardian in the slicerFlags table then I get a return value of 1 but if I select either Oakpoint or Orthoselect then I get a -1 even those there are 2 rows in the table that have either word in the FlagsConcat column.  I tried putting spaces before and after the comma but that made no difference.  Anyone know why the contains() function isn't showing true when looking for Oakpoint or Orthoselect?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CONTAINS` does not perform string searches; it tests for presence of values by equality tests. The docs admittedly don't do a good job of describing this unambiguously. You want something like `COUNTROWS(FILTER(Flags, CONTAINSSTRING(Flags[FlagsConcat], SELECTEDVALUE(SlicerFlags[FlagNames])))) > 0` instead (disclaimer: not tested).

Comment: I tried using ContainsString also but when I try to put the CONTAINSSTRING(Flags[FlagsConcat] , its gives me an error.  Cannot find name '[FlagsConcat]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jeroen's code is correct...

```
Contains = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Flags, CONTAINSSTRING(Flags[FlagsConcat], SELECTEDVALUE(SlicerFlags[FlagNames]))))+0
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wasn't working for me then I realized I needed to remove the >0 in order to use the Contains measure as a filter.  Thanks a lot.  Wish I could give you both the Rep but not sure how to give any to Jeroen.